# Global event listener JAVA

Tags: java, swing, keyboardfocusmanager

I want to listen keyboard event over all control in my jframe to show new window, so far this is my code :

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
                .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent evt) {
                      int key = evt.getKeyCode();
                         if (evt.isControlDown() && key == KeyEvent.VK_F1) {

                           JManualTransction FrmManual = new JManualTransaksi();  
                           FrmManual.SetVisible(true);  

                          }
                        return false;
                    }
            });
```

But the problem is the FrmManual window is always show twice when i press CTRL + F1
May somebody can tell me why?

thanks ....

Comment: You're likely getting a key pressed AND key released event.  This isn't actually the best choice, in fact you might find using a key binding is generally easier. See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Yes I get pressed and released even so i add KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, thanks